# how to color the phylogenic dendrogram labels based on species traits with ggtree?

Tags: r, ggtree

I made a phylogeny dendrogram with Vphylomaker and plotted with ggtree.

Here is a data example.

```
species <- c("Physaliastrum japonicum", "Azolla imbricata", "Ligularia sibirica","Silene repens var. apoiensis", "Eriocaulon amanoanum")
genus <- c("Physaliastrum", "Azolla", "Ligularia", "Silene", "Eriocaulon")
family <- c("Solanaceae","Salviniaceae","Asteraceae","Caryophyllaceae","Eriocaulaceae")
traits <- c("Forest","Wetland","Lake","Forest","Lake")

  data <-data.frame(cbind(species,genus,family,traits))

devtools::install_github("jinyizju/V.PhyloMaker")  
library("V.PhyloMaker") # load the package 
example <- data.frame(data[,1:3])  # input example species list 
tree.a <- phylo.maker(sp.list = example, tree = GBOTB.extended, nodes = nodes.info.1, scenarios="S1") # generate the phylogeny 

library("ape")
library("Biostrings")
library("ggplot2")
library("ggtree")

ggtree(tree.a$scenario.1,layout="fan", open.angle=0)+
  geom_tiplab()
```

[image]

I would like to color the labels (species) based on the information of traits(forest, wetland etc.) in "data".